# Don't collapse past wrapContent during adjustResize

Tags: android-layout, android-constraintlayout

This layout has two input fields and a button. When the layout resizes (due to the soft keyboard being shown for the input fields) the button, which was previously aligned with the bottom of the layout, gets drawn over the input fields. The goal here is to make sure none of these views end up overlapping on small screens; on large screens the adjustment for window resizing is perfect.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/message"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="20dp"
            android:text="@string/long_message"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/top_input"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="20dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/message">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/bottom_input"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="20dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/top_input">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

    <Space
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/cta"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/bottom_input" />

    <Button
            android:id="@+id/cta"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="20dp"
            android:text="@string/forward"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

I've tried putting in a Space view (as in the pasted XML) just to add a constraint so that this won't happen, but it seems to get ignored. I've tried adding a Guideline, but it requires a particular percentage or distance, which doesn't apply here.

[image: This is ignoring the Space view's constraints.]

What's the right way to do this? It really surprises me that the Space view's constraints there are being ignored.

Answer (score 3):

you can do this by below 
first just add   `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"` to your related activity.

then you have to just put

`android:fillViewport="true"` into your `NestedScrollView` and it will work 
please try below XML code.

```
<androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true">
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/message"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="20dp"
            android:text="What's the right way to do this? It really surprises me that the Space view's constraints there are being ignored."
            android:textSize="18sp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/top_input"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="20dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/message">

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />
        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/bottom_input"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="20dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/top_input">

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/cta"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:text="forward"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/bottom_input"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.995" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Comment: by trying below solution it will not overlap on other view and also let scroll if the size of edit text is large it is the perfect solution.